# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm getting an error when running my local site.

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()

mysqli.ini file is showing in /etc/php/7.0/mods-available.

Also, when I run the command `php -m | grep -i mysql` I can see mysqli but still nothing.

When I run `phpinfo()` in the browser though I can't see a mysqli section so I'm guessing the module isn't enabled?

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure mysql is running? Try starting the service.